# C# Sqlite connection does not fail on wrong password

Tags: c#, sqlite

This is how i create a database and put a password:

```
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(filePath + "/" + username + ".sqlite");
        dbconnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filePath + "/" + username + ".sqlite;Version=3;");
        dbconnection.Open();      
        dbconnection.ChangePassword(password);
        sychroniseDb("Create");
```

This is how i check if i can connect to the database:

```
    try{
       dbconnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filePath + "\\" + username + ".sqlite;Version=3; Password=" + password + ";");
                        localDbConnected = true;
                        dbconnection.Open();
                        return true;
    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("User or password incorrect");
                        localDbConnected = false;
                        return false;
                    }
```

The problem in this whole thing is that even if the password is wrong it's still passes the Try and doesn't go in the Catch and even opens the connection. The dll are the ones from Nuget Packages. I have Visual Studio Express 2013.

The real problem is that when i do a query it tells me is encrypted or its not a database but why it passes that try catch?

From the Sqlite website it tells that if its wrong it shouldn't connect.

Comment: What library are you using? .NET does not support SQLite without third party APIs so your statement "Sqlite website it tells that if its wrong it shouldn't connect." is not helpful because that behavior depends on the implementer of the API.

Comment: ADO.NET Data Provider for SQLite version 1.0.94.0.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have passwords... If you have access to the file, you have access to the database. The token is probably just ignored.

Comment: Ok then why when i give wrong password its just crashes the query? Something isn't right. I guess its just checking when it query's? Still its not making any sense.

Comment: Do you check if the dbconnection is open before you execute the query? Is the dbconnection reporting a state of IsOpen?

Comment: Yes it's says it's open but if i do a query it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. To be thrown exception must be made some commands. Try the following code:

```
try
{
    var dbPath = Path.Combine(filePath, (username + ".sqlite"));
    var csb = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = dbPath, Version = 3, Password = password };
    dbconnection = new SQLiteConnection(csb.ConnectionString);      
    dbconnection.Open();
    //COMMENT: Any command to check whether the database is encrypted
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA schema_version;", dbconnection))
    {
        var ret = command.ExecuteScalar();
    }       
    localDbConnected = true;
    return true;
}
catch(SQLiteException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("User or password incorrect");
    localDbConnected = false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes i did the same but with a select version of sqlite and it worked as a charm. Still i don't understand why it makes you the connection if its incorrect. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

According to System.Data.SQLite documentation, SQLiteConnection implements System.Common.DbConnection.

```
SQLite implentation of DbConnection.

For a list of all members of this type, see SQLiteConnection Members .

System.Object    MarshalByRefObject
      Component
         DbConnection
            SQLiteConnection

public sealed class SQLiteConnection : DbConnection, ICloneable
```

The MSDN documentation states:

> Notes to Inheritors When you inherit from DbConnection, you must
>   override the following members: Close, BeginDbTransaction,
>   ChangeDatabase, CreateDbCommand, **Open**, and StateChange. You must
>   also provide the following properties: ConnectionString, Database,
>   DataSource, ServerVersion, and State.

On DbConnection.Open the MSDN documentation states:

> Opens a database connection **with the settings specified by the
>   ConnectionString.**

Thus, it makes sense for implementers to only check the password when you actually open a dbconnection. Not in the constructor.

Comment: Ok, so still i have dbconnection.Open() in the try catch. Why it opens the connection then?

Comment: Are you actually able to get data from the database? Maybe some of your assumptions are wrong (the database has a password, it found the database, the database isn't empty or the database was properly saved by the code you used to create it).

Comment: No if i put the wrong password it will bypass the try catch block and then will fail on Command.noQuery or any Query. 

If its the good password everything is nice and smooth.

It just bypass dbconnection.Open() like its working perfectly. Tried restart remaking the db nothing solves it.